# How to convert an observable to it's type?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

If I have an `Observable<T>` is there a way to convert it to T?

i.e.

```
let sum$: Observable<number>;
let sumNum: number;
```

how can I have `sumNum` be set to the value in `sum$`?

I have found that `sum$.subscribe(sum => sumNum = sum);` will do it but it creates a subscription which is not what I want. I want it to set the value once and not subscribe anymore.

Comment: `.take(1).subscribe(...)` or `.first().subscribe(...)` or `toPromise(...)`

Comment: So I'm doing an HTTP request and for some reason the first subscribe using `.take(1)` is not producing the right number, `.take(2)` does. would those other methods like `.toPromise` avoid that problem?

Comment: No, `take(1)` and `first` are identical. `toPromise` waits for completion but your http request should complete. Can you show your http request code?

Comment: It may be hard to explain I'll try to think of a minimal code example.

Comment: @ZacharySchwatz Please provide feedback on the answers you got or mark the answer as accepted if it answered the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have an Observable is there a way to convert it to T?

If I understand correctly, you want something like (the non-working!)

```
const value = obs$.first().value();
```

The answer is: no, that's not possible. Observables are streams of data *over time*, so such a function would have to block (which is a horrible idea – what if `obs$` takes five minutes to emit?). Blocking and how to avoid it is the very reason things like promises have been born. Blocking is bad.

The correct solution is what has been mentioned in the comments:

```
obs$.first().subscribe(value => this.value = value);
```

This will create a subscription which is unsubscribed the very moment `obs$` emits because `first()` causes the chain to complete in this case. So there is nothing to be scared of about this solution.

---

As a small addendum, `BehaviorSubject` does come with a `getValue()` method that synchronously returns the latest value. This can be guaranteed because it's like a `ReplaySubject` with an initial value, i.e., at any given point in time it had at least one emission. However, resorting to `BehaviorSubject#getValue()` is *usually* a sign of doing something wrong.